# OLS estimator derivation: second-order condition to prove global minimum?

Tags: regression

In deriving our ordinary least squares estimates, we can partially differentiate the sum of squared errors $\sum_{i=1}^{n} {e_i^2} = \sum_{i=1}^{n} {(Y_i- \hat{\alpha}-\hat{\beta}X_i )^2}$ with respect to our estimators $\hat{\alpha}$ and $\hat{\beta}$ to get the following first order conditions:

$$\frac{\delta SSR}{\delta \hat{\alpha}}= -2\sum_{i=1}^{n} {e_i}=-2\sum_{i=1}^{n} {(Y_i- \hat{\alpha}-\hat{\beta}X_i)}=0$$
$$\frac{\delta SSR}{\delta \hat{\beta}}= -2\sum_{i=1}^{n} {X_i e_i}=-2\sum_{i=1}^{n} X_i {(Y_i- \hat{\alpha}-\hat{\beta}X_i)}=0$$

How can we then prove that the sum of squared residuals is a global minimum?

Firstly, can I confirm that the Hessian looks like this?

\begin{array}{cc}
   2n & 2\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i  \\
   2\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i  & 2\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i)^2  \\
  \end{array}

Secondly, how can I show that the determinant of this Hessian is positive definite, i.e. $ 4[n \sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i)^2 - (\sum_{i=1}^{n}X_i)^2]>0?$ The presentation bears some resemblance to the population variance formula, and I know that variance must be non-negative, but I'm wondering how to move on. Is there some way to factorise this? Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

It seems that you working on the right lines. By multiplying out the brackets, it can easily be verified that $n\sum{X}_i^2 - (\sum{X}_i)^2 = n\sum{(X_i - \bar{X}})^2$ where $\bar{X}$ is the mean. As you yourself spotted, this is basically a standard expression for the variance. From this, it follows that $n\sum{X}_i^2 - (\sum{X}_i)^2 > 0$ provided that $X_i \neq \bar{X}$ for some $i$.

Incidentally, you also need to verify that one of the second derivatives is positive (say $SSR{_{\alpha\alpha}}>0$) which follows directly from your Hessian.

Comment: The condition requires $n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2>(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)^2$, not $n (\sum_{i=1}^n X_i)^2 > \sum_{i=1}^n X_i^2.$

Comment: Good answer (+1)

Answer (score 1):

The conditions you derive guarantee that $(\hat{\alpha}, \hat{\beta})$ occur where SSE is locally minimized. Since our estimates are unique, i.e. there is a unique parameter vector that satisfies our first-order conditions, we know the selected parameter vector minimizes the objective function in the interior of the parameter space.

To determine whether this is a global minimum, you would compare the SSE under our estimates to the boundary points. For a simple linear regression as you've described, the parameter space is $\mathbb{R}^2$, and is therefore unbounded so $(\hat{\alpha}, \hat{\beta})$ globally minimizes SSE. In contrast, if you had, for example, the restriction that a parameter was non-negative, checking the boundary condition would matter for determining a global minimum of SSE.

Comment: The fact that the first order conditions hold does not mean that we have a minimum - it might be a maximum! (Or neither.) This is why we need to take a look at the matrix of second derivatives

Comment: When I said the conditions you derive, I meant the first-order conditions and the second-order conditions.